# Get a sub-collection's parent-document's id

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Consider the following image:

[image]

I am writing a cloud function in Node.js and have created a function that gets triggered when a user writes a message in a messageRoom. When the function is triggered it has a snapshot of the message document in the `messages` sub-collection.

Is there a way for me to get the id of the parent document e.g `2AelOkjccuGsfhXIcjWR`, which contains the right sub-collection?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code you have written so far.  It will be easier to answer the question if we see where you're at.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the tip. I wanted to make the question as general as possible. WIll remember your tip next time i ask a question

Comment: There are a lot of mistakes to be had when programming - on Stack Overflow it's **always** helpful to see the code, because there might be a problem that's different than the one you suspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your function is triggered "when a user writes a message in a messageRoom" the document path should be like `messageRooms/{roomId}/messages/{messageId}` and the Cloud Function should look as follows. You can then use the context Object and simply do `context.params.roomId`.

```
exports.getParentId = functions.firestore
    .document('messageRooms/{roomId}/messages/{messageId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        const parentDocId = context.params.roomId;
        console.log(parentDocId);
        //...
     })
```

---

If your Cloud Function is different and you cannot use `context`, another solution consists in using the `parent` properties of the [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#parent) on one hand, and of the [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#parent), on the other hand.

Something like:

```
    const snapRef = snap.ref;   //Reference of the Document Snapshot
    const messagesCollectionRef = snapRef.parent;  //Reference of the messages collection (i.e. the parent of the Document)
    const roomRef = messagesCollectionRef.parent;  //Reference of the room doc (i.e. the parent of the messages collection)
    const roomId = roomRef.id;   //Id of the room doc
```